# Increment padding with wildcard

Tags: css

I have a function which creates an arbitrarily deep unordered list like such (with stuff in-between). The HTML output looks like;

```
<ul class="side-nav-level-0">
     <ul class="side-nav-level-1">Stuff</ul>
     <ul class="side-nav-level-1">Stuff</ul>
     <ul class="side-nav-level-1">Stuff
         <ul class="side-nav-level-2">More Stuff</ul>
             <ul class="side-nav-level-3">Even More Stuff</ul>
         </ul>
     </ul>
     <ul class="side-nav-level-1">Stuff</ul>
</ul>
```

I am using CSS wildcards to select the ul classes

```
ul[class^='side-nav-level-'] { styling }
```

This works nicely for selecting all the classes, but I wish to indent the list like so

```
-Stuff
-Stuff
-Stuff
    -More Stuff
        -Even More Stuff
-Stuff
```

Currently it looks like this

```
-Stuff
-Stuff
-Stuff
-More Stuff
-Even More Stuff
-Stuff
```

How can I get the incrementing classes to increase the left-padding incrementally using CSS? I was thinking something with `nth-child` but I can't think how to increase the padding size each time.

My last option is to in-line the style within the function, but I was curious if there is a CSS solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with using `padding-left`?

```css
ul[class^='side-nav-level-']{
    margin: 0; /* reset browsers default margin styles*/
    padding-left: 20px; /* add some padding value */
}
```

```html
<ul class="side-nav-level-0">
    <ul class="side-nav-level-1">Stuff</ul>
    <ul class="side-nav-level-1">Stuff</ul>
    <ul class="side-nav-level-1">Stuff
        <ul class="side-nav-level-2">More Stuff
            <ul class="side-nav-level-3">Even More Stuff</ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav-level-1">Stuff</ul>
</ul>
```

Note: You didn't close the `<ul>` on your `.side-nav-level-3`

```
<ul class="side-nav-level-3">Even More Stuff<ul>
                                         ---^---
```